# In Young's double slit experiment, does the intensity of light depend on the slit width?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, interference, diffraction

Here's a question I just came around
**In YDSE, the intensity of the maxima is I.If the width of each slit is doubled, what will be the intensity of maxima now ?**
here, we assume that no diffraction is occurring.

*what I thought was that the intensity is power per unit area, therefore even though more light is coming in but the area factor will cancel it hence the intensity must remain same.*

But the answer was 2I and was according to the direct relation of slit width and the intensity of light.

please tell where I m wrong?

Also, I saw a proof online where the person is treating two dependent variables as independent.

[Here's the link check it too.](https://youtu.be/6GGQhEngUCg)

Comment: @Farcher but the OP says "no diffraction is occurring", which means geometric optics, which means they're not slits, they're big holes, which mean the intensity doesn't change.

Comment: @JED I take your point.

Comment: @JED I want to clarify we are just assuming that diffraction is not happening, although it will happen in reality...

Comment: @Farcher I want to clarify we are just assuming that diffraction is not happening, although it will happen in reality...

Answer (score 1):

The width of the slits has nothing to do with the separation of the fringes.

Doubling the width of each of the two slits leaves the separation of the fringes the same but each fringe will now have twice a much light forming it.

So the answer is $2I$.

Comment: No,as I said in my question the intensity must not change..please tell where I am in that logic

Comment: Also another case which might be  considered is when we take power of source to be same(quite convincing) then as width doubles area becomes twice therefore intensity will decrease....

Comment: In any case ,Intensity must not increase